# Which sampling distributions of the normal correspond to which sample statistics?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, sampling, sample

**Question:** Which sampling distributions of a normally distributed, i.e. $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, population correspond to which sample statistics?

In particular, which sample statistics (if any), do the:

- $\chi^2$ distributions
- $t$ distributions
- $F$ distributions

correspond to?

**Motivation:** This information isn't well-organized in any of the sources I have found, hence why I am asking this question here: so that there can be at least one well-organized reference. Ideally an answer would be in tabular format, with one column the sample statistic, and the other column the sampling distribution corresponding to that sample statistic for a normal-distributed population.

I am looking only for sample statistics for which *exact* answers are known. Answers along the lines of "the central limit theorem applies in the large $n$ limit" are not what I am looking for -- if that is the best possible answer for a given sample statistic, then there is no need to mention that sample statistic or its sampling distribution.

**Definitions:**
- [sample statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistic): A function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, i.e. $f(x_1, \dots, x_n)$.
- [sample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_(statistics)): $n$ independent draws from the normal distribution, i.e. a random vector with $n$ entries whose joint distribution is equal to the product of its marginal distributions. Denoted by $X$.
- [sampling distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_distribution): For a given statistic $f$, the distribution of the random variable $f(X)$.

**Example:**

*Sample Statistic:* $f = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \quad $   *Sampling Distribution:* $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$

*Sample Statistic:* $f = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n x_j)^2}$ *[Sampling Distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StandardDeviationDistribution.html):* PDF $\frac{2}{\Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2})}\left(\frac{n-1}{2x^2} \right)^{(n-1)/2} x^{n-2}\exp\left(\frac{-n+1}{2} \right)$

Comment: This is kind of backwards: one ordinarily begins with a statistic and works out its sampling distribution.  The problem with how you have framed this is that it's too broad and open-ended: there are infinitely many statistics that could be formed for which the sampling distributions could be computed exactly.

Comment: @whuber No, it's not too broad, because as I state explicitly, I just want to know, at a minimum, how the $\chi^2$, $F$, and $t$ distributions fall into this framework, but if anyone wants to include any other sampling distributions, that is fine as well. Also, how is it backwards -- I am beginning with a statistic and working out its sampling distribution? Just because the words "sampling distributions" occur first in the sentence before "sampling statistics" doesn't mean that's their order in my thinking. Also, they're in the order you mention ***everywhere else in the question***.

Comment: @whuber While I appreciate you keeping an open mind, I think you may be interpreting the question more broadly than it needs to be interpreted. The question isn't about statistics that _could_ be formed for which the sampling distributions could be computed exactly -- the question is about statistics which _already exist and have been used_ for which the sampling distributions _already have been_ computed exactly.

Comment: Answering that version correctly would require a comprehensive and detailed review of an enormous body of literature covering all of science, social science, and theoretical and applied statistics.  That's a compelling argument why this question is too broad for our framework.

Comment: @whuber I didn't know that admittedly -- I thought it was far fewer. While I could continue attempting to argue with you for the sake of my pride and point out that all I was really interested were the few (<5) distribution families mentioned in intro stats textbooks, as I tried to state in the body of my question after "in particular", I already have an answer which addresses these, so it is a moot point.

Comment: Just to show that I'm not making this up, a great number of the commonly described distributions on Wikipedia or in the handbooks arise naturally as statistics for normal distributions: Gammas are proportional to chi-squares; noncentral t, F, and $\chi^2$ in the usual ways; betas for correlation coefficients; extreme value distributions for standardized maxima and minima; lognormal for exponentials of normals; uniforms for p-values; and then there are transformations: logitnormal, folded normal; and then truncations; and mixtures arising from censoring; and on and on and on... .

Comment: There are perhaps hundreds of statistics which are distributed as $t$, $\chi^2$ or $F$, because of a relationship with the normal. This is definitely too broad as it stands. As whuber says, the framing of the question has it backwards. Any time you get a statistic where it satisfies the conditions to have a t-distribution -- numerator is normal (with 0 mean under the null), denominator has the same scale, is independent of it, and is distributed as the square root of a ch-square on its degrees of freedom - then the statistic will have a $t$ distribution, and there are very many like that...ctd

Comment: ctd... Similarly $F$ and $\chi^2$. Indeed, it's a common way to construct a new statistic -- starting with (or constructing) something that you're willing to assume to be normal, make a statistic with one of those standard distributions using the relations those distributions have with the normal. If we look to your broader question (the first sentence), the issue expands much further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is clearly already sophisticated and extensive. I certainly can't produce a complete catalog, but some that are known are:

- Sample mean is normal with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma / \sqrt{n}$
- Sample variance is $\chi^2$ with $n - 1$ dof.
- Sample standard deviation is $\chi$ with $n - 1$ dof.
- Deviation of sample mean from true mean, measured in sample standard deviations, is Student-t with $n$ dof.
- I'm not sure about full exact distributions for the sample raw and central moments of arbitrary orders. But certainly it is possible to derive a closed formula for any desired moment (or cumulant) of such a distribution.
- The sampling distributions of order statistics are expressible exactly in terms of the normal CDF and PDF, but these expressions are difficult to work with numerically. Analytic forms for their moments (e.g. means and variances) are not known, but there are several controlled approximations.

F distributions arise from the ratio of the variances of two independent samples from a normal population. Pearson R distributions arise from computing the correlation coefficient of two independent samples from a normal population.

Comment: So F distributions arise from the proportions of sample variances? I.e. $$f(x_1, \dots, x_n, x_{n+1}, \dots, x_{2n}) = \frac{Var(x_1, \dots, x_n)}{Var(x_{n+1}, \dots, x_{2n})} \,?$$

Comment: @Chill2Macht: Yes. More generally, if $z \sim N(0, 1)$, then $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{m} z_i^2}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} z_j^2} \sim F(m, n)$$

Comment: Oh that's neat. Do you mean $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^m z_i^2}{\sum_{j=1}^n z_{j+m}^2} $$ though? I am not sure whether I understand (I re-read the Wikipedia article about the $F$ distribution, but it was overly wordy.)